# Impossible to debug a docker containerized Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have an app in Rails 7.0.4.3, Ruby 3.2.2 and tailwindcss-rails 2.0 in a docker container.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  changes-log:
    image: changes-log
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Image "changes-log" contains **CMD "/bin/bash"**.

In a console window, I run "docker-compose up".  Next in another one, I run "docker attach containerName".

For starting the app I run bin/dev.

Prifile.dev

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch[poll]
```

In index action method of the controller, I have a debugger breakpoint for debuging the app in this point, but, although the app flow is stopped in the indicated line, it doesn't show the indicator (rdbg) for inputing commands for debug.   I have to break the app for stop it.

I have searched for information about it, but all I have found say It should work.

I need help, please.

Thanks !!

Comment: I might set up a development environment using a tool like `rbenv`, without involving Docker, and try to reproduce your issue using that.  Just the Compose file you have here doesn't really describe what's in that image, or what might be in the Ruby environment; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a million possible solutions depending on a million different things.  But here's the easy advice:

Don't do `docker compose up`.

Instead:
`docker run --rm -it container_name bash`

And inside the container do `bin/rails tailwindcss:watch[poll] &`
And then `bin/rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0`

Your app should break normally.

And once that works you can try to get fancy with IDEs and the like.